# psloglist -w into a file

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I'm trying to redirect windows event log continuously into a file.

psloglist.exe has the -w feature (that listens for new events and outputs to console) so I tried combining it with redirection into a file like so:

```
psloglist -w > out.txt
```

It doesn't work. As new events are logged they do not show up in the file.

However, if I remove `> out.txt` new events do shows up in the console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I do not know how Windows (or this application) handles writing to files - if this were Perl, I would set the output to unbuffered.

[A quick minute of Googling confirmed my thoughts.](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=20666&PID=109756)

Comment: thanks. psloglist outputs each event immediately with the -w switch. There's no buffering that I can see. If anything it's the redirection (>) itself that might be adding the buffering, but that seems strange. If that were true it would have been the same for every command line program in Windows...

Comment: Yes, the buffering is on writing to the output file, as explained in that link. No, not every command-line program has to exhibit the same buffering behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409474/why-do-some-cmd-launched-processes-block-buffer-output-when-the-output-is-redirec
Here's an explanation as to why one command-line program may buffer output, and another won't (when redirected to a file). It depends on how they are written.

Comment: 4k buffering is indeed what's happening. But the .cmd workaround didn't fix it. Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?